# Why do we care about functions of the integrator?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

Ito's lemma states that

$$f(X(t))=f(X(0))+\int_0^tf'(X(s))dX(s)+\frac12\int_0^tf''(X(s))d\langle X\rangle(s)$$

Why are we interested specifically in deterministic functions of the integrator $X(t)$? In applications, where do the objects $f$ and $X$ usually come from?

Comment: The main interest is in solutions of SDEs; in the autonomous case like this (which is indeed interesting) you generally have $dX_t=b(X_t) dt + s(X_t) dY_t$. This is basically the stochastic version of forces depending only on position and not explicitly on velocity, except that now the forces are random so it is their distribution that depends on velocity. In fact what I just said is closely related to a second order problem where the stochastic term appears only as a force; converting this to a first order problem in some asymptotic regime is called Kramers-Smoluchowski approximation.

Comment: Even if you aren't interested in solving SDEs Ito's lemma is important. For example, it tells you when a $C^2$ function $f(X_t)$ of a semimartingale $X$ is a local martingale by explicitly giving the semimartingale decomposition of $f(X)$. This is helpful in proofs you might give of e.g. Levy's characterisation of BM, Girsanovs theorem and the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality.